# how can we use conditional operater to switch on 4 different pages in react js?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I use conditional operator for switch on two different pages and it is working.

```
{window.location.pathname.slice(1) == "blogs" ?
 <Blogs {...props} setLoad={() => loading()} /> :
<Competition {...props} setLoad={() => loading()} /> 
}
```

But now I have four pages then how can we use conditional operator to switch on different pages.
or Is there any other method to switch on different pages.

Comment: What you are looking for is react router https://reactrouter.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the logical AND operator to achieve that if you dont want to spin up a multipage router. Once the left condition is true, the component on the right of the expression is rendered

```
{
  window.location.pathname.slice(1) === "blogs" && <Blogs {...props} setLoad={() => loading()} />
  window.location.pathname.slice(1) === "competition" && <Competition {...props} setLoad={() => loading()} /> 
  window.location.pathname.slice(1) === "extrapages" && <ExtraPage />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform I would recommend you to use React Routers which are easy to user

> It has these switch router concept as well

```js
 ReactDOM.render((
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
         <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
         <Route path="/explore" component={Explore} />
       </Switch>),
       document.getElementById('root')
   );
```

[React Router Docs](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Switch)